# How to redirect a university personal webpage to an internal ip

Tags: html, redirect, webserver

We have a webserver managed by our department and each of us have a personal web space url like:

http://students.university.edu/myusername (1)

we can access to our webfiles folder and edit index.html and have other data. I think we also have php server installed with our department webserver so we can also make a php website.

But I want to setup a webserver on my machine in my lab and redirect any access to my personal webspace above (1) from any external client anywhere around the world to my webserver on my local machine. In other words I don't want to use the webserver managed by our department IT because basically I need access to my files on my computer. And as you may notice my machine's ip is local in our infrastructure and invisible from outside. Is there any suggestions?

Comment: You would have to write a whole proxying system just to accomplish this. It would likely be much easier just to put your website on something publicly accessible.

Comment: Do clients `around the world' have access to your machine? I.e. Even if you redirect your hosted site to your machine, will the general public even have network access to it? FTPing files from your machine to the hosted server is probably your best bet.

Comment: clients have access to university website and also university webpage but not my machine because the my machine's ip is local and invisible from outside of our network!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to host pages from your local machine, which is buried behind (possibly multiple) layers of obfuscation in the university's network... and you want those pages to be viewable on the WWW. The answer is effectively no. -- It is technically possible, but you would need administrative access to the network, so that you could configure it to your particular needs. Of course, you could just ask the IT department if they'll set that up for you (and they may, depending on their mood and policy) but for security reasons, it's not likely they'll grant the request.

Answer (score 0):

found this article that says in the .htacces file on your server, add

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 192.168.0.0/24

that should block everyone but the people on ips 192.168.0.0 through 192.168.0.24

of course if u dont have the .htacces file, which you should, you have to create the file in text editor, just calling it .htaccess with no extension

hope this helps

Comment: Actually I don't want to block anyone. I want to redirect on my webserver on my local machine. .htaccess can redirect to another website but not to local ip.

Comment: what exactly do you need to do, its a little hard to understand sorry, do you want to access you personal computer files from work or vice verse?